# Pass limit & offset to request - Facebook SDK for Android 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

I can modify POST params using

```
session.setParams(session.getParams(...).putString(...))
```

Now I want to pass offset and limit. There is no function like setGETParams(...) and getGETParams(...). How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Request all set up, you can add additional parameter like this:

```
// Get the current request parameters
Bundle myRequestParams = myRequest.getParameters();

// Add the additional parameters
myRequestParams.putString("limit", "100");
myRequestParams.putString("offset", "20");

// Update the request parameters
myRequest.setParameters(myRequestParams);
```